# VS Code: how to get process ID via shell command in launch.json?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In our Visual Studio Code configuraiton launch.json looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "fb-python",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to a running Python process",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
            "subProcess": true,
            "justMyCode": true,
            "redirectOutput": true,
            "django": true,
            "client": "instagram"
        }
    ]
}
```

It shows process selection dialog every time I click "Debug". What I want to do is to calculate the process ID using a shell command:

```
ps -ef | grep "async uWSGI worker 1" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'
```

How can I do that without writing a custom extension?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do it?